# Is there any proper way through which we can check whether a number is rational or not

Tags: rational-numbers

Is there any proper way through which we can check whether a number is rational or not because finding the decimal expansion at times is not viable. For example the number $48/121$ shows no sign of termination or repetition of its digits well to around 12 to 13 decimal places but is actually rational.

Comment: Not following.  The number $\frac {48}{121}$ is obviously rational.  What are you asking?

Comment: If you have a number like $e$ or $\pi$ for which you can use analytic methods to write out the decimal, it can be extremely difficult to determine rationality.  Usually methods specific to the number or the functions that produce it are needed.

Comment: If you divide `a/b` where `a` and `b` are integers, you get a rational number. "Rational" comes from "ratio", and a division is just that -- a ratio!

Comment: @Mohd Khan 0.39669421487603305785123966942149

Comment: Sure, it's $0.\overline {3966942148760330578512}$.

Comment: Just to say, if you take an irrational number like $e$ and divide it by a huge power of $10$, say $10^{10^9}$, you'll get an irrational number for which the decimal starts with a colossal string of $0's$...about a billion $0's$ in this case.  If that's all you look at, it sure looks rational for a long time, but it isn't.

Comment: thanks captain america

Comment: @lulu,thanks a lot

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 has posted a wildly inaccurate (terminating!) decimal expansion of the number in question. The version posted by lulu is what you want.

Comment: @CameronBuie I'm so sorry! I wasn't even paying attention to my notation! If anyone is willing, could you show me how to represent non-terminating decimals through mathjax?

Comment: @MohdKhan Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Depends entirely how expressed.  One would have doubts about
$$   \sqrt[3]{-2 + \sqrt 5} +  \sqrt[3]{-2 - \sqrt 5} $$
but be more certain about the real-valued root of
$$ t^3 + 3 t + 4  $$

Answer (score 1):

**Ratio**nal numbers are written as ratios, i.e., fractions.

If you can write it as a fraction, it's rational. Otherwise, no. If it repeats or terminates, it's rational. Otherwise, irrational.

Answer (score 1):

In order to decide if a decimal representation is that of a rational number or not, you need all (infinitely many) digits, and that's never going to happen.  You cannot determine if it rational or not from finitely many digits from its decimal.

The task you apparently want to do is not possible to carry out by human or computer. You could, though, pick a rational that is very very close to the decimal expansion in question.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a fraction of two integers, say $m/n$ with $n\ne 0$  then it is rational.

If it is presented by its decimal expansion then you check to see if it has eventualy repeating or terminating decimals.

If none of those happen then it is not rational.

Some numbers such as $\pi$ or $e$  or $\sqrt n$ if $n$ is not a perfect square, have been proved to be irrational.

Some very interesting questions are out there regarding irrational numbers.

For example finding two irrational numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $  \alpha ^{\beta}$ is rational.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a summary of several comments, that may help.

A number is rational if it can be written as the quotient of two integers. That's the *definition*, so there's no need to ask how to show that $48/121$ is rational. There it is as a quotient of integers.

There is a theorem that says that a number is rational if and only if it has a decimal representation that is eventually periodic (it might have a whole bunch of zeroes at the end; that counts). So you know that if you work out the decimal expansion of $48/121$ it will eventually have a repeating block - even if you have to look further than you are willing to calculate to see it.

Looking for a repeating block is rarely a good way to see whether a number is rational. Usually you have to try a different kind of argument. There are well known ones that show $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, but they don't work by proving there is no repeating block in $1.4146\ldots$.

You can sometimes argue directly from the decimal expansion. The number
$$
0.1010010000001000000000000000000000000100\ldots
$$
where the number of zeroes between the ones follows the factorial pattern
$$
1, 2, 6, 24, 120, \ldots
$$
is not rational. (It's even *transcendental*, but that's a longer story.)

Comment: I think it might be good to note that "[arguing] directly from the decimal expansion" might work to nudge you towards a hypothesis but is by no means a proof.

Answer (score 0):

All numbers in the form

$$\frac p q \quad p,q\in \mathbb{Z}\quad q\neq 0\iff \frac p q\in \mathbb{Q} $$

are defined rational. Usually to guarantee an unique representation we set $q$ positive and $(p,q)=1$ that is relatively primes.

In such cases we can't have doubts.

When we face with decimal expression it can be shown that when the decimal part becomes eventually periodic the number has a rational expression (there are simple algorithms to reconstruct the fraction from the decimal expression).

Comment: Any repeated decimal is rational.

Comment: What do you mean with repeated? isn't it included in "periodic"?